# why doesn't my code work within a function?

Tags: r, list, function, attributes

I have created two list with my data set, I am my code helps to match the two list if there are elements in one list that are not in the other using attributes that have been assigned to the two list.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2011"), dmy("01-01-2013"), by = "days"), 300)
ID <- rep(c("A","B", "C"), 300)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)

# Create first list
int1 <- df %>%
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(month == "1") %>% 
  group_split()

# Create second list
int2 <- df %>%
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(month == "2") %>% 
  group_split()

int1 <- int1[-c(3,6)]


# Convenience function to grab the attributes for you
check <- function(list, attribute_name) {
  return(attr(list, attribute_name))
}

# Add an attribute to hold the attributes of each list element
attr(int1, "match") <- data.frame(id = sapply(int1, function(x) paste(x$ID[1])),
                                  interval_start_date = sapply(int1, function(x) paste(x$new[1]))
)

# Check the attributes
check(int1)

# Add an attribute "tab" to hold the attributes of each list element
attr(int2, "match") <- data.frame(id = sapply(int2, function(x) paste(x$ID[1])),
                                  interval_start_date = sapply(int2, function(x) paste(x$new[1]))
) 

# Check the attributes
check(int2)

# Creates an index for the two list based on the attributes, 
i1 <-  with(check(int2, "match"), paste(id, format(as.Date(interval_start_date),
                                                               "%Y-%d"))) %in%  
  with(check(int1, "match"), paste(id, format(as.Date(interval_start_date), 
                                                          "%Y-%d")))

out <- int2[i1]
```

The code works, and it correctly provides the output, but when I put the code into a function, it ends up giving an error and ultimately does not work.

```
match_intervals <- function(attribute_name, list1, list2, id_col, interval_col){
  
  # Creates an index for the two list based on the attributes, 
  i1 <-  with(check(list2, attribute_name), paste(id_col, format(as.Date(interval_col),
                                                                 "%Y-%d"))) %in%  
    with(check(list1, attribute_name), paste(id_col, format(as.Date(interval_col), 
                                                            "%Y-%d")))
  
  out <- list2[i1]
  return(out)
}

int2 <- match_intervals(attribute_name = "match", int1, int2, id, 
                        interval_col = interval_start_date)
```

I get this error:
`Error in as.Date(interval_col) : object 'interval_start_date' not found` and/or
`Error in as.Date.default(interval_col) :  do not know how to convert 'interval_col' to class “Date”`

Any thoughts on what might be happening and how I can fix this?

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

We may pass the input column names as string and then use `[[` instead of `with`

```
match_intervals <- function(attribute_name, list1, list2, id_col, interval_col){
  
  # Creates an index for the two list based on the attributes, 
  dat2 <- check(list2, attribute_name)
  dat1 <- check(list1, attribute_name)
  i1 <-   paste(dat2[[id_col]], format(as.Date(dat2[[interval_col]]),
                                                                 "%Y-%d")) %in%  
    paste(dat1[[id_col]], format(as.Date(dat1[[interval_col]]), 
                                                            "%Y-%d"))
  
  out <- list2[i1]
  return(out)
}
```

-testing

```
int2 <- match_intervals(attribute_name = "match", int1, int2, "id", 
                        interval_col = "interval_start_date")
> length(int2)
[1] 7
```

---

According to `?with`

> For interactive use this is very effective and nice to read. For programming however, i.e., in one's **functions**, more care is needed, and typically one should **refrain from using with()**, as, e.g., variables in data may accidentally override local variables, see the reference.

Comment: Would you happen to know what this error means? `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'closure'` I get it when I try it on my actual data set which is very similar to the example data set for this question.This error is happening around the `i1` object.

Comment: None of the `list` elements have `NULL` values.

Comment: I ran it, I included an image of the output in the question.

Comment: @JohnHuang your code shows `id` and `interval_` without quotes.  In my code, I used quotes.  Can you add the quotes

Comment: @JohnHuang if I pass unquoted arguments, I get the same error.  `match_intervals(attribute_name = "match", int1, int2, id, 
+                         interval_col = interval_start_date)
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'closure'`

Comment: @JohnHuang Does that work for you `feb <- match_intervals(attribute_name = "match", list1 = july, list2 = feb, id_col = "id", 
                        interval_col = "interval_")`

Comment: Yes, it worked great! Sorry, missed that detail. Thank you so much!